# Combine CSS with a variable php

Tags: php, html, css

```
<?php
    if ($username)
        echo $username 
     else
        echo '<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="login.php">
                <button class="btn btn-custom">Log ind</button>
              </form>';
?>
```

I have this code and I want to be able to push my $username variable to the rightside, where my Login button was, when an user logs into my side. How would this be done?

I can't use 
     `echo <p class="btn btn-custom"> <? $username; ?> </p>`
what would be a possible way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `$username` in a div/span element and align it like you want with css (maybe you can reuse the css class you used for your login link).

Example:

```
<?php
    if ($username) {
        echo '<div class="navbar-form navbar-right">' . $username . '</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="login.php">
                <button class="btn btn-custom">Log ind</button>
              </form>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do so is like this: you can echo a variable following a string with

`echo 'string whatever'.$variablename.'more string';`

```
<?php
    if ($username)
        echo '<div class="username">'.$username .'</div>';
     else
        echo '<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="login.php">
                <button class="btn btn-custom">Log ind</button>
              </form>';
?>
```

and then simply give the class `.username` the same positioning as `navbar-right`

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to use div with float right style, float right style push the content on right side.

```
<?php
if ($username)
    echo '<div style="float:right">' . $username . '</div>';
else
    echo '<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="login.php">
        <button class="btn btn-custom">Log ind</button>
      </form>';
?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "use this code"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard ! thanks, I will take care about this also update it. Please let me know if you have any further suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you looking for this:

You are in right direction but need to use the `echo` statement to print `$username`

```
<?php
    if ($username)
        echo '<p class="btn btn-custom">' . $username . '</p>';
     else
        echo '<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="login.php">
                <button class="btn btn-custom"><?php echo $username; ?></button>
              </form>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $username; ?>
```

Best way to implement this will be making use of smarty template.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($username) {
  echo '<div style="float:right">'.$username . '</div>';
}
else {
  echo '<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="login.php">
    <button class="btn btn-custom">Log ind</button>
   </form>';
}
?>
```

Use CSS' `float:right` attribute to push the `$username` to right.